# Using "User" global variable in SOQL query

Tags: soql, standard-objects, global-variables

I want to retrieve some data from an object to a List according to the ID of the logged in User, so I am trying this soql query

```
List<Object> = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Object WHERE User_id = : $User.Id];
```

but it doesn't work for me. So how could I get the logged in user ID ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The global object for User information inside Apex is actually [`UserInfo`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_UserInfo_static_methods.htm). Try:

```
List<Object> = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Object WHERE User_id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```